# Mysql Join get Latest value of each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql  version: 8.0.21

I am lookig of get the latest value of each "TableData" which has the type "fruit".

```
Table Name: TableNames
 _________________________________________
| id | name         | id_group  |   type  |
|-----------------------------------------| 
| 0  | AppleGroup   | apple     |  fruit  |
| 1  | BananaGroup  | banana    |  fruit  |
| 2  | OtherGroup   | other     |  other  |


Table Name: TableData
 __________________________
| id |  id_group  | value  | 
|--------------------------| 
| 0  | apple      |  12    |
| 1  | banana     |  8     |
| 2  | apple      |  3     | <--get latest
| 3  | banana     |  14    |
| 4  | banana     |  4     | <--get latest
```

With this Query I get all the items, but I am looking for the lastest of each.
I already tried to group by and order by, but the problem is that I first need to order by and then group by,  seems  that's not possible in Mysql.

```
SELECT 
  n.name,
  d.value
  FROM TableNames n
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableData
  ) d ON d.`id_group` = n.`id_group` 
  WHERE type = 'fruit'

Expected ouput:
 _____________________
| name        | value |     
|---------------------|
| AppleGroup  | 3     |
| BananaGroup | 4     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `ROW_NUMBER()`, because you can be on an older version of MySQL (before 8.0), you can create an inner join with the max(id):

```sql
SELECT 
  TableNames.name,
  TableData.value
FROM
    TableData
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    id_group,
    MAX(id) as max
  FROM TableData
  GROUP BY id_group) x  ON x.id_group = TableData.id_group
INNER JOIN TableNames on TableNames.id_group = TableData.id_group
WHERE x.max = TableData.id
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ij2KrsQ2)

Comment: That did the trick, still to much to learn. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT tn.name, tn.id_group, td.value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.id_group ORDER BY td.id DESC) rn
    FROM TableNames tn
    INNER JOIN TableData td
        ON td.id_group = tn.id_group
    WHERE tn.type = 'fruit'
)

SELECT name, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id_group;
```

For optimization, you may consider adding the following index to the `TableData` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON TableData (id_group);
```

Note that on InnoDB, MySQL will automatically include `id` at the end of the index, hence the index is `(id_group, id)`.  This should let MySQL efficiently do the join in the CTE and also compute `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: it's working, you save my day.   it's any chance to do the same query but avoiding to collect that big buffer from the first Select inside the "cte" ?

Comment: @johnnytolengo It is not a buffer so much as a necessary subquery (any method you use will require a subquery...somewhere).

Comment: The problem becomes when the TableData gets too large (+million rows) the Mysql timeouts because the SELECT inside the cte search every single row. Maybe it's another efficient way to do so..

Comment: Try adding a relevant index, q.v. my updated answer above.